# How to change Swagger-ui URL?

Tags: swagger-ui

I have tried to change the swagger URL, right now i have "http://localhost:8080/context-root/rest/swagger-ui.html", i want it to be "http://localhost:8080/swagger". I tried using the DOCKET.Host("swagger"), but browser is spinning. And its not loading screen.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can any one help with that?

Comment: We cannot access your localhost site, so you should add some screenshots

Comment: @Polarbear0106  issue is i how to change that URL to http://localhost:8080/swagger in springfox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Path Provider ?

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    @Profile({"!production"})   
     public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


        @Autowired
        private ServletContext servletContext;

        @Bean
        public Docket api() {

            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .host("localhost")
                    .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
                        @Override
                        public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                            return "/swagger";
                        }
                    })
                    .protocols(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(protocols)))
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this won't work for me, I can't see Swagger UI on localhost:8080/swagger